# how to use the unique tag with a slice of struct in gin Go framework?

Tags: validation, go, go-gin

I'm trying to use **gin framework** to validate a slice of struct in order to ensure the slice is unique.

With The following code:

```golang
type CreateOrderParam struct {
    Items           []*CreateItemParam `form:"items" binding:"gt=0,required,unique,dive"`
}

type CreateItemParam struct {
    Dress *CreateDressParam `form:"dress" validate:"required"`
}

type CreateDressParam struct {
    Id int `form:"id" validate:"gt=0,required"`
}
```

I use the following JSON to test the code:

```json
{
    "items": [
        {
            "dress": {
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "dress": {
                "id": 1
            }
        },
        {
            "dress": {
                "id": 3
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

However,the JSON pass validation.So **I doubt that the unique tag not being used correctly.**My question is:**how to use the unique tag to validate the slice of struct?**

Answer (score 0):

In short, validation with `unique` on the slice elements amounts to comparing those elements with the `==` operator. Actually the implementation of `gopkg.in/go-playground/validator.v10`, which Gin depends on, constructs a map with reflection, but that's essentially the same thing.

So `CreateItemParam` — as all structs — compares with `==` by comparing the fields recursively, however the field `Dress` is a pointer type. Two pointer types are equal if they have the same memory address, irrespective of what the pointed values are.

If you change the struct definition to:

```
type CreateItemParam struct {
    Dress CreateDressParam `form:"dress" validate:"required"`
}
```

validation will then compare the actual `CreateDressParam` struct values instead of the pointers, and fail the `unique` check as you expect.

If you can't change the struct definition, you might have to register a custom validator *into Gin's validator engine*:

```
type CreateOrderParam struct {
    Items []*CreateItemParam `json:"items" binding:"gt=0,required,unique_struct_with_ptr,dive"`
}

func main() {
    r := gin.New()

    if ginvalidator, ok := binding.Validator.Engine().(*validator.Validate); ok {
        ginvalidator.RegisterValidation("unique_struct_with_ptr", func(fl validator.FieldLevel) bool {
            v := fl.Field().Interface().([]*CreateItemParam)
            // implement uniqueness for these structs
            // return true if validation passes, false otherwise
        })
    }
    // ... rest of router code
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! Your answer solve the problem.Thanks again!